# How to fix CORS with Angular App hosted on Heroku?

Tags: angular, heroku, cors, mean-stack

I have followed this [article](https://itnext.io/how-to-deploy-angular-application-to-heroku-1d56e09c5147) (01.10.2019 12:15) to deploy Angular App on Heroku, actually worked fine on my laptop.

However, opening in my Cellphone the requests did not work. I am working with MEAN stack.

Basically the **backend** is in node express, which communicates with **MongoDB** and handling the documents.
I also hosted the backend on Heroku which returned a link like *"backend.appheroku.com".* If I run this in PostMan, e.g, to make requests it works fine. It does not matter which device I am requesting (Ex: GET backend.appheroku.com/users).

In **FrontEnd** Angular App, of course, I have created a service.ts so that I make requests such as GET, POST and so on…The Heroku also returned a link like *"frontend.appheroku.com"*. This works fine in my Laptop, however, running that link in my Cellphone I am not able to make requests anymore from the FrontEnd App. Ex "frontend.appheroku.com/users" requests the "users" collection from "backend.appheroku.com"/users and display with HTML the results.

I just know this is from **CORS** issue, however, I still did not find the solution. I have also tried to follow the steps from https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html but no success as well.

Backend.js file:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

app.get('/users', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for all origins!'})
})

let port = process.env.PORT || 3050;

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on Heroku port')
})
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have to enable CORS support for your backend. Check the docs https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html or search for a blog post explaining how to do it with node express or MEAN.

Comment: I tried that too. "Enable All CORS Requests" section.

Comment: Please add the relevant code from your backend and the cors error message you get to your question.

Comment: You also have to enable preflight requests: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Answer (score 1):

I had to add code below in my backend.js (Thanks @[fridoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9423231/fridoo)):

```
app.options('*', cors()) // include before other routes
```

In package.json I had also to add the **"heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"**:

```
{
    "postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod" // add this for heroku
},
```